# Css: how to fix li's in one line

Tags: html, css

My li's aren't in one line. How do I fix this?
I need to have 3 columns and on the same line.
How do I do this? 
Thanks!

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHrYf.png)
My HTML:

```
<main>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>

                <li><a href="movie.html">Movies</a></li>
                <li><a href="quote.html">Quote per category</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
        <img src="assets/img/banner.png" alt="banner" title="banner">

    </header>
    <section>
       <h1>Movie db search</h1>
        <article>
        <ul>

        </ul>
        </article>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy copyright Robin Hennebel. Data fetched from <a href="https://www.themoviedb.org/" title="themoviedb"
                                                                target="_blank">Tmdb</a> and <a
                href="https://api.chucknorris.io/" title="cn.io" target="_blank">Chucknorris.io</a></p>
    </footer>
</main>
```

So you can see my li's where i put a picture and a paragraph via fetch.
I need them to be in one line in 3 columns.

My CSS:

```
    article ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 30%;
}

article li:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #A0C0FF;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

article li:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #F897CA;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-left: 1%;
}

figure img{
    width: 35%;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

figcaption{
    padding: 2%;
}

figure {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
article{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Does anyone has a solution?

Comment: Your css only styles li in article, but your li are in header and nav but not in article.

Comment: Maybe you should re organised your code and post it again and if you can add sample on how you want it to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**METHOD 1:** Use flexbox, that's the cleanest & most modern answer. You already use flex elsewhere, and you can make use of all of its magical powers...

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul li {
  flex: 1 0 33.3%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Apples</li>
<li>Oranges</li>
<li>Bananas</li>
<li>Pears</li>
<li>Mangos</li>
<li>Peaches</li>
<li>Plums</li>
</ul>
```

However support for flexbox in older browsers is iffy. Test it in IE11, does it work?

**METHOD 2:** You can resort to a more classic way, using display:inline-block (fyi I use width: 30%, for some odd reason 33.3% results in two columns)...

```css
ul li {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Oranges</li>
    <li>Bananas</li>
    <li>Pears</li>
    <li>Mangos</li>
    <li>Peaches</li>
    <li>Plums</li>
</ul>
```

**Method 3:** Or using float: left, my personal favourite over the years, before becoming a flex addict ...

```css
ul li {
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
   <ul>
        <li>Apples</li>
        <li>Oranges</li>
        <li>Bananas</li>
        <li>Pears</li>
        <li>Mangos</li>
        <li>Peaches</li>
        <li>Plums</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: IE11 will display correctly if you use the correct prefixed styles. Also, method two isn't desirable because of the awkward "extra spacing" you get with inline/inline-block. That's why 33.3% isn't working for you there. Methods one and three are good. +1

Comment: Aha thx for this. I've rarely ever used inline-block, float and flex work much better, but I leave it up to OP to explore.

Answer (score 0):

replace css code like this

your li in header nav

```
nav ul li {
display:inline-block;
width: 30%;
}
nav li:nth-child(even){
   background-color: #A0C0FF;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
 nav li:nth-child(odd){
background-color: #F897CA;
border-radius: 25px;
margin-left: 1%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9twyyafs/